# Remove row in dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataframe:

```
       ID  Tell  Number 
0       1   Perhaps 2   
1       1   Yes     6
2       1   No      9
3       2   Yes     4
4       2   Ye      7
5       2   No      8
6       3   Ye     15
7       3   Perhaps 2
8       3   No      6
9       3   Yes     2 

# Creating the dictionary
dic = {'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 'Tell': ['Perhaps', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes','Ye', 'No','Ye', 'Perhaps','No', 'Yes'], 'Number': [3,6,9,4,7,8,15,8,6,13]}

# Creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

I want my program to be able to remove every row from my dataframe if the number is higher then 6 and the Tell column is either Ye or Yes.

I want it to look like that:

```
       ID  Tell  Number 
0       1   Yes     2   
1       1   Yes     6
2       1   No      9
3       2   Yes     4
4       2   No      8
5       3   Yes     2
6       3   No      6
7       3   Yes     2
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
df=df.loc[((df['Number'] < 6) & (df['Tell']!='ye')& (df['Observation']!='Yes'))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.query`:

```
print( df.query('not (Number > 6 and Tell in ["Ye", "Yes"])') )
```

Prints:

```
   ID     Tell  Number
0   1  Perhaps       3
1   1      Yes       6
2   1       No       9
3   2      Yes       4
5   2       No       8
7   3  Perhaps       8
8   3       No       6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have a column `Observation` which you have not given us. Try;

```
 df[(df['Number']<6)&(df['Tell']!='Ye')&(df['Observation']!='Yes')]
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be an error in this line:

`df=df.loc[((df['Number'] < 6) & (df['Tell']!='ye')& (df['Observation']!='Yes'))]`

I see that there is no `Observation` column and also your df has `Ye` and you have `ye` your condition. That might be the issue possibly. So try capitalizing `ye` to `Ye` and `Observation` to `Tell`

`df=df.loc[((df['Number'] < 6) & (df['Tell']!='Ye')& df['Tell']!='Yes'))]`

Let me know if that was the issue.